# jquery on keyup trigger css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble getting this short script to work. I want to set the `width` and `height` of a `div` by taking the values of input elements.

```
<input id="width" type="number" class="num" />
<input id="height" type="number" class="num" />
<br />
<br />
<div>
</div>

var w = +$('#width').val();
var h = +$('#height').val();

var width = w * 10;
var height = h * 10;

$('.num').keyup(function(){
$('div').css({
    'width' : width,
    'height' : height
});
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/djd0jqo1/1/)

**How can I get this to work?**

Comment: Move the variables into the handler.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/djd0jqo1/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.num').keyup(function(){
  var w = +$('#width').val();
  var h = +$('#height').val();
  var width = w * 10;
  var height = h * 10;
  $('div').css({
    'width' : width,
    'height' : height
  });
});
```

You need to get the val the moment the person changes, they way you coded, it gets the value of width and height the moment the script is run, and it doesnt ever change.

Comment: doesn't work when you click on the arrows on the `input=number`. so annoying

Comment: You can add the same code for the click event @JosanIracheta , and it fixes your arrow problem

Comment: I switched it to `change` and that works for the arrows and the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick version you can start working with that only adjusts the width.  Once you get that working, then add height.

```
$('#width').keyup(function(){
  var w = $(this).val() * 10;
  $('div').css('width',w);
});
```

Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/djd0jqo1/12/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.num').keyup(function(e){
 var w = +$('#width').val();
 var h = +$('#height').val();
 var width = w * 10;
 var height = h * 10;
if(width!=0)
{
$('div').css(
    'width' , width+"px"

)
}
  if(height!=0)
 {
  $('div').css('height',height+'px');
 }
 });
```